# SQL Select One extra 'false' row per join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    O.Id AS OrganisationId, o.Name as OrganistionName, 
    pt.product_type_name as ProductType
FROM 
    [Content].[Organisations] O (nolock)
JOIN 
    [Content].[ProductOrganisations] PO (nolock) ON PO.OrganisationId = O.Id
JOIN 
    [dbo].[report_info] R (nolock) ON PO.ProductId = R.report_id
JOIN 
    [dbo].[CONTENT_ProductTypes] PT (nolock) ON R.[product_type_id] = PT.PRODUCTTYPEID
WHERE 
    O.ShowCompanyPage = 1 
GROUP BY 
    O.Id , o.Name, PT.PRODUCTTYPEID, pt.product_type_name 
ORDER BY 
    o.Name, pt.product_type_name
```

Which returns the following results:

```
OrganisationId  OrganistionName ProductType
1       Coca Cola Company   Article
1       Coca Cola Company   Book
1       Coca Cola Company   Company Profile
2       PepsiCo Inc.        Audio Conference
2       PepsiCo Inc.        Book
2       PepsiCo Inc.        Company Profile
3       Pfizer, Inc.        Article
3       Pfizer, Inc.        Company Profile
3       Pfizer, Inc.        Credit Rating Report
```

But I need to to add in an extra "false" row per organisation.

This row should occur as the first row, and the ProductType should be blank.

For example:

```
OrganisationId  OrganistionName ProductType
1       Coca Cola Company   
1       Coca Cola Company   Article
1       Coca Cola Company   Book
1       Coca Cola Company   Company Profile
2       PepsiCo Inc.        
2       PepsiCo Inc.        Audio Conference
2       PepsiCo Inc.        Book
2       PepsiCo Inc.        Company Profile
3       Pfizer, Inc.
3       Pfizer, Inc.        Article
3       Pfizer, Inc.        Company Profile
3       Pfizer, Inc.        Credit Rating Report
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could add `UNION SELECT DISTINCT OrganisationId, OrganisationName, '' as [ProductType] FROM [[[same as prev query here]]]`

Comment: Since it seems that accuracy is important you might want to take a look at this article before you continue littering your queries with nolock. It is NOT a magic "go fast" button. It has some very serious side affects that many people do not understand. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: @JoeMalpass - you solution gives me a blank ProductType every 2nd row unfortunately. I need a blank ProductType as the start row of each organisation. Any ideas?

Comment: @SeanLange Ok thank you for letting me know the side effects, this is not the final query, it is just for testing purposes at the moment. But i have learned something new here, thank you.

Comment: @fourbeatcoder try `UNION ALL` instead, it takes a bit longer to execute but should remove duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a union to create this:

```
SELECT O.Id AS OrganisationId, o.Name as OrganistionName, '' as ProductType
FROM [Content].[Organisations] O (nolock)
JOIN [Content].[ProductOrganisations] PO (nolock)
ON PO.OrganisationId = O.Id
JOIN [dbo].[report_info] R (nolock)
ON PO.ProductId = R.report_id
WHERE O.ShowCompanyPage = 1 
GROUP BY O.Id , o.Name

union

SELECT DISTINCT O.Id AS OrganisationId, o.Name as OrganistionName, '' as ProductType
FROM [Content].[Organisations] O (nolock)
JOIN [Content].[ProductOrganisations] PO (nolock)
ON PO.OrganisationId = O.Id
JOIN [dbo].[report_info] R (nolock)
ON PO.ProductId = R.report_id
WHERE O.ShowCompanyPage = 1 
GROUP BY O.Id , o.Name
ORDER BY o.Name, pt.product_type_name
```

Comment: your solution will not work. 
It will just give me the organisation list with ALL blank ProductType for each row. Please take a look back over my original post to see the data i need returned and edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Write your `GROUP BY` statement with `ROLLUP` like this:

```
GROUP BY O.Id, o.Name, ROLLUP(PT.PRODUCTTYPEID, pt.product_type_name)
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to do this with rollup.. nice work

Comment: this does not work, it gives me an 50% more rows per organisation, all with a null o.Name and all at the start of the organisation. See my answer provided for the solution that worked.

Comment: @JamieD77 It is not the correct solution, even if i use 'ROLLUP(pt.product_type_name)' this gives me 50% more rows per organisation, each extra row with a null pt.product_type_name at the start of the organisation. I wanted one extra row per org. See my answer, it works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33655766/976537

Comment: that's because your desired result in the original post looks nothing like what you actually wanted to see.

Comment: this is your original select.. `SELECT O.Id AS OrganisationId, o.Name as OrganistionName, pt.product_type_name as ProductType`.. where is your `PRODUCTTYPEID` and `COUNT(R.report_id)` that you included in your self answer..

Comment: @fourbeatcoder I was a little too bit quick yesterday, the `ROLLUP` needs to be put around the ProductTypeID, of course. I edited the answer. While a solution with `UNION`works also, of course, I recommend to look at `ROLLUP` and `CUBE`, because these are built-in functionalities for creating subtotals; they provide better performance and your queries become easier to maintain!

Answer (score 0):

Similar to advice from @JoeMalpass in comments in op above, here is how I solved it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT O.Id AS OrganisationId, o.Name as OrganisationName, 0, '' as [product_type_name],  0 AS ProductsInType
FROM [Content].[Organisations] O (nolock)
WHERE O.ShowCompanyPage = 1 

UNION

SELECT O.Id AS OrganisationId, o.Name as OrganistionName, PT.PRODUCTTYPEID, pt.product_type_name,  COUNT(R.report_id) AS ProductsInType
FROM [Content].[Organisations] O (nolock)
JOIN [Content].[ProductOrganisations] PO (nolock)
ON PO.OrganisationId = O.Id
JOIN [dbo].[report_info] R (nolock)
ON PO.ProductId = R.report_id
JOIN .[dbo].[CONTENT_ProductTypes] PT (nolock)
ON R.[product_type_id] = PT.PRODUCTTYPEID
WHERE O.ShowCompanyPage = 1 
GROUP BY O.Id , o.Name, PT.PRODUCTTYPEID, pt.product_type_name
```

Comment: this query doesn't look like the result you wanted in the original question.. your `For Example` only has 3 columns.. that information is important.

Comment: @JamieD77 you are incorrect -  The amount of columns is not relevant to the question

Comment: so if you tell us you wanted a 3 column result.. we're supposed to assume you wanted 5?

Comment: try to be more specific next time... you're doing 3 distincts.. `Select Distinct, Union, Group By`.. that's poor sql

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94835/discussion-between-jamied77-and-fourbeatcoder).

Comment: @fourbeatcoder understanding the number of columns in the query *is* relevant to providing a good quality answer. It can make the difference between returning the correct number of rows Vs a bunch of duplicates because of the way SQL aggregates results. Clearly, you were able to figure out the correct union/distinct/group syntax to get the results you wanted based on your complete data set. However, it's not really fair to attack other users for pointing out how you could have improved your question. JamieD77 was providing a constructive criticism there.That sort of discussion is welcome on SO

Comment: @JamieD77 also duly noted, thank you, I did not realise that my 'Select Distinct, Union, Group By' is poor sql.

Comment: While a `UNION` works, of course, I would still invite you to have a look at the `ROLLUP` statement. It is a built-in functionality of SQL server for creating subtotals.